# Dont understand the exitcode result of a proccess

Tags: python, .net, process, teamcity, exit-code

my use case is that I use TeamCity http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/ to build some projects and run tests on them.

In my test i create .net process and run on it python method (via RPyC) that return number 7.

```
exit(7)
```

I execpt that when my process will exit his exit code will be 7.
and this indeed what happen the proccess exit with exit code 7.

```
Assert(7, p.ExitCode)
```

But... when I run the same use case in other computer the test run and return 7 to the proess but the test failed becouse the return code of the process is always 0 and not 7 and the Assert methods return false.

I thought that even if the process failed for some reason, his exit code should be -1 or other non zero integrer and not 0 so any suggestion why this happen?

It must be some issue with the test environments becouse the same code works in other computers so what could couse to this?

Computers difference:

The good (pysichal computer):
CPU: Intel xeon E5440 2.83 GHz
RAM: 2 GB
OS: Win7 32 bit

The bad (virtual computer):
CPU: Intel xeon X5680 3.33 GHz (2 processors)
RAM: 3.5 GB
OS: Win7 Service pack 1 32 bit

Etid:

in the computer that i got failed there an issue that when the shell run i getting the following error: "UNC path are not supported". this happened becouse the shell opened with the desktop path which is net path. then the path changed to default path c:\windows. but the strange here that the process keep runing well and no exception occur and also the exid code is 0 and not 1 or -1 so i'm still dont understand why this happen

Answer (score 0):

> It must be some issue with the test environments becouse the same code works in other computers so what could couse to this

The most likely culprits are often the Environment (like you might encounter in [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)) and race conditions.  Start with the easy stuff: compare the execution environment in both places.